# Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving

Tags: sales-order

I am getting below error on order view page in magento 2, what is the reason for this error.

```
Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.
```

Comment: Have you checked in you log?

Comment: I am not getting anything in logs

Comment: Any solution?????

Answer (score 2):

This is usually because of an Exception.

Looking at the PHP Logs

```
tail -50f  /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

I found this error:

```
[11-Jan-2020 04:53:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Relation::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track, instance of YYYY\OrderTrackingUpdate\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track given, called in /var/www/html/vhosts/sharath/XXXXXXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 in /var/www/html/vhosts/sharath/XXXXXXXXXX/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0
```

Turns out, in my case, there was a preference in one of my custom module's `di.xml` (that I had overlooked) that was causing the issue.

Once I fixed that - the Order Details pages rendered by just fine.

I hope this helps! :)